# Bad Request (#400): Не удалось проверить переданные данные

Tags: php, yii2

Вызываю ajax запрос.

csrf в заголовках передается

```
X-CSRF-Token: fEER1XgjIYdNbVLUNkTf0cUaZd4Ycq2FA8qCyvtOS4ImJFmAPBBT1CkKMZIGfIyavVQNtnMrytNJ_--vuQwywA==
```

На локалке работает, как залил на хостинг, ловлю эту ошибку. 
Если отключить csrf, то норм.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если $this->enableCsrfValidation = false, то все норм. Но я не хочу отключить csrf

Comment: Возможно на хостинге настроено так, что данные из заголовка X-CSRF-Token не передаются в скрипт

Comment: как это проверить?

Comment: var_dump($_SERVER) и посмотреть есть ли данный заголовок и значение

Comment: А что у вас проверяет CSRF токены? В Laravel этим занимается VerifyCsrfToken middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf), а у вас? Опять же, учитывайте что он не статичен и генерируется заново для каждой сессии.

Comment: echo Html::csrfMetaTags(); прописано в layout?

Comment: Проверяет Yii. Да, прописан в layout

Comment: токен должен быть одинаковый для backend и frontend, если у вас advanced

Comment: если локально работает, а на хостинге косяки, то копай в сторону передачи заголовков

Comment: Был похожая проблема. Решил так: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877691/266650)