# Как сделать logout в backend

Tags: php, yii2

Пишу код приложения на yii2-advanced, решил сделать авторизацию и выход из учетной записи для админа в **backend** через контроллер в **frontend**.

Авторизацию сделал, все хорошо работает, а вот с выходом не получается.

Выскакивает ошибка : *Не удалось проверить переданные данные.*

Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил ошибку так:

Поменял в config/main  в front и back end строчки:

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' =>
        '_csrf-front/back end' на '_csrf-site'
```